# Ruby and Rails: setting current_user if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm in a controller method.

```
p current_user
p request.referrer != Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.dashboard_patients_add_url
if request.referrer != Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.dashboard_patients_add_url
  p 'in here'
  current_user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])[0]
end
p current_user
```

Returns

```
#<User id: 33, first_name: "1", last_name: "1", working_at: "1", password_digest: nil, password_confirmation: nil, created_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", updated_at: "2014-03-20 00:38:00", email: "aab@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$nw1UHb0PeFUFh17zKRhbsOA.MirNfXW69wj7aRfMSDEw...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", last_sign_in_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", authentication_token: "HHz6KyqrHF7pC41DyGKH", salutation: "1", speciality: "1", cell_phone_number: "1", office_phone_number: "1">
false
nil
```

So the if statement is false and the p within the if statement is not run...which would lead me to believe that current_user should not get set to the User.find_by_authentication_token result. However, clearly, it does. If I comment out the if statement, then I get

```
#<User id: 33, first_name: "1", last_name: "1", working_at: "1", password_digest: nil, password_confirmation: nil, created_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", updated_at: "2014-03-20 00:38:00", email: "aab@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$nw1UHb0PeFUFh17zKRhbsOA.MirNfXW69wj7aRfMSDEw...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", last_sign_in_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", authentication_token: "HHz6KyqrHF7pC41DyGKH", salutation: "1", speciality: "1", cell_phone_number: "1", office_phone_number: "1">
false
#<User id: 33, first_name: "1", last_name: "1", working_at: "1", password_digest: nil, password_confirmation: nil, created_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", updated_at: "2014-03-20 00:38:00", email: "aab@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$nw1UHb0PeFUFh17zKRhbsOA.MirNfXW69wj7aRfMSDEw...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", last_sign_in_at: "2014-03-20 00:37:54", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", authentication_token: "HHz6KyqrHF7pC41DyGKH", salutation: "1", speciality: "1", cell_phone_number: "1", office_phone_number: "1">
```

As expected. I have no idea why anything within that if statement would have any impact on anything since its condition is false.

I've clearly misunderstood something extra basic, and I'd love for someone to clear my vision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `current_user` a method?  I'm going to assume it is.

The first time you ask for `current_user`, it is a method, and it is returning that result.  Then, it gets past the if-statement and the interpreter sees that you have defined a LOCAL VARIABLE to `current_user` (you haven't assigned anything, but you have now overwritten the method, in the local scope, with a local variable of the same name).  That local variable has no value, it is `nil`, so you get `nil`

Do you have a `current_user=` method?  You need to use "self.current_user = {stuff}" if you want to use the method, instead of defining a local variable.

Example:

```
class MyClass
  def current_user
    @current_user
  end
  def initialize(u)
    @current_user = u
  end
  def current_user=(u)
    @current_user = u
  end
  def do_things_bad
    p "current user is #{current_user}"
    if false
      current_user = "something else"
    end
    p "current user after if is #{current_user}"
  end
  def do_things_good
    p "current user is #{current_user}"
    if false
      self.current_user = "something else"
    end
    p "current user after if is #{current_user}"
  end
end
thing = MyClass.new("Nathan")
#<MyClass:0x00000100c5def0 @current_user="Nathan">
thing.do_things_bad
#=> "current user is Nathan"
#=> "current user after if is "
thing.do_things_good
#=> "current user is Nathan"
#=> "current user after if is Nathan"
```

Comment: I understand the above. However, I thought anything within an if statement would not be executed unless its condition was met. What I'm hearing you say is that the local variable wasn't assigned a value (which would be the execution and would have occurred if the condition of the if statement had been met), but that the code within the if statement was implemented in the sense the local variable "current_user" was put in the local scope and that overwrote the method. Is that correct?

Comment: Well even though it wasn't run, the interpreter sees that local variable and it's overwritten from thereafter... See my edit for an example that shows the problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is even though the code in the if statement isn't being executed, it's still being parsed, and Ruby is creating a local variable `current_user` which prevents access to the method. The code doesn't have to run for Ruby to define the variable for you.

This is the same reason why we don't see any errors when we run this code:

```
if false
  bar = "foo"
end
bar #=> nil
```

whereas running this code does generate errors:

```
baz #=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `baz' for main:Object
```

Comment: "The code doesn't have to run for Ruby to define the variable for you." - and that was the key piece I was missing. Thanks!